# Cannot run Qt Creator GUI outside of Qt. "The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)" error

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-errors

I downloaded C++ code from GitHub to tag images for training an object detector using Machine Learning.

Within Qt Creator 4.2.1 Based on Qt 5.8.0 (MSVC 2015, 32bit), I was able to compile and run the code. Unfortunately, I was not able to run the .exe outside of Qt Creator.

Initially, I received an error that

```
"The program can't start because libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll is missing".
```

Thanks to  
      [QT The program can't start because libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33137441/qt-the-program-cant-start-because-libgcc-s-dw2-1-dll-is-missing), that was fixed easily by adding

```
"QMAKE_LFLAGS += -static"
```

to the .pro file. Now, when I run it I get

```
"The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). Click OK to close the application."
```

I was able to reproduce the error using the simple "Hello World" default project that appears when you create a Qt Widget Application.  This led me to believe something was wrong with my installation.

Based on the advice of this article: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12099117/32-bit-qt-application-on-win-7-x64-wont-run-but-runs-fine-from-qt-creator`, I used **Dependency Walker** to identify possible causes.  I expected to see only a few items that I can follow up on. Instead, I received a list of close to 100 missing .dll files. All the files started with

```
"API-MS-WIN ###.DLL" or "EXT-MS ###.DLL"
```

where ### represent some additional text characters, for example;

```
"API-MS-WIN-SHCORE-STREAM-WINRT-L1-1-0.DLL"
```

I'm attaching a sample output.

[image: Screen Capture of Dependency Walkder]

Another suggestion was to copy over

```
libwinpthread-1.dll, libstdc++-6.dll, libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll.
```

That did not work either.

My next move was to simply get the latest version of QT and wish for the best. I installed Qt Creator 4.8.1 Based on At 5.12.0 (MSVC 2015, 32 bit). This time, I could not even get the code to run in the IDE. I received 1000+ error messages!

Based on advice from several pages, I added

```
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
```

to the .pro file and it still would not compile.

Also, I verified that the application is being built as a 32bit application. I'm running on a 64 bit Windows 10 system.

If anyone would like to take a crack at it to see if they can create a working .exe, here is the link: github.com/clavicule/BBTag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out! My installation of Anaconda (a Python distribution popular for data science and machine learning) is the culprit.

From: @remy-lebeau

[The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10492037/the-application-was-unable-to-start-correctly-0xc000007b)

The error:

```
"The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b) ..."
```

is a good indicator that the 32-bit app tried to load a 64-bit DLL. At first, this did not make sense since I verified many times that I was using the 32 bit version of Qt.

It turns out that the installation of the 64 bit version of Anaconda also contained many Qt5 dlls used for the PyQt5 package. Since the path to this folder came before the path to my c:\Qt...\bin folder, it was used in the build instead of the actual 32 bit version installed with Qt. This was not obvious because I was unaware of PyQt5 so I had no idea that it came with Anaconda. A simple reordering of the path entries using the System Environment Variables interface AND a system restart fixed the problem.

Silver lining:  I now know C++ and designing GUIs w/ QT and PyQt5

Thanks @albertmand and @jwernerny

Comment: Glad you found that obscure problem!

Answer (score 2):

Qt provides a tool to copy the necessary dlls to the folder of your executable.

The tools is called windeployqt.exe and comes with your Qt installation. For me it is located at `C:\Qt\5.9.1\msvc2015_64\bin\windeployqt.exe`. You will have to look at your installation path and probably the msvc_32 folder to find it.

Then you go to the folder with your executable in it, oben a command prompt or powershell and execute `path\to\windeployqt.exe yourProgram.exe` and it will automatically copy the necessary dll files to this folder. Afterwards you can run your program without issues.

The official documentation for the tool can be found [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html).

Alternative 1: While developing you could use QtCreator which automatically adds the paths to the dlls when running your program - make sure to include them if you deploy your program!

Alternative 2: Add the path to the necessary dlls to your PATH variable. This isn't recommended either, since everyone who gets your program would have to do the same to run it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It copied 23 DLLs into the folder including some subfolders but, unfortunately, I still get the same error.  Fed up, I uninstalled both versions of Qt and started from scratch using the Qt v5.5 as suggested on the Github page. I still get the same error message.  I tried a year ago, ran into the same issue, and gave up. I'm trying not to give up now.  The GitHub page also has a binary but it will not run either.  If anyone would like to take a crack at it to see if they can create a working .exe, here is the link: https://github.com/clavicule/BBTag

Comment: Sometimes windeployqt misses a few things. I have found that running it on the directory containing the executable sometime picks things up that won't be picked up otherwise. I have also found that sometimes I need to specify specific modules to add (e.g. --opengl --printsupport). Look carefully at the DLLs it says it is missing to figure out what to add.

Comment: @jwernerny Thanks for the tip on running it against the containing folder. I'll try that out when I get back to my machine. The error message I'm getting does not mention any DLLs anymore and the Dependency Walker identified over 100.  These are Windows DLLs and I can't imagine that I'm supposed to located and transfer that many DLLs. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20045015/how-can-i-make-visual-studio-copy-the-required-dll-files-into-the-release-folde  looks to have another way to copy over the dlls.  Hopefully one of these methods work. Thanks all.